# Magento 2.4.1 admin tfa configuration page is blank

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4, two-factor-authentication

I just migrated from Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.1 , after i logged in from the backend i was redirected to TFA configuration page, but it shows blank container like this:

[image]

i already ran these commands below, but nothing changes

```
bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/general/force_providers google
bin/magento config:set twofactorauth/google/otp_window 60
bin/magento in:rei
bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: Have you configured it from admin?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i'm stuck at this page, can not enter admin dashboard at all?

Comment: First you can disable and login into the admin and then setup it again.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the cli commands where you set the secret for the user.

```
bin/magento security:tfa:google:set-secret admin helphelphelphelp
```

Then goto your google authenticator app. Click Enter a setup key. As key use helphelphelphelp. This worked fine for me and I used the new code to login to magento afterwards.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html

Comment: for step #3 , where should i put the .credentials  file?

Comment: Hmm, you might not have to do this step, what if you test without? It could be this file is needed for the testing framework. Just try to set the secret and see what happens

Comment: same still blank

Comment: I see, still blank... do you have any console errors?

Comment: no console error , i check the log file also no error

Comment: What if you try another authentication method? Do you get anything then ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The blocks for the login.content container, defined in the xml layout files (e.q. `vendor/magento/module-two-factor-auth/view/adminhtml/layout/tfa_google_configure.xml`) where not loaded.

I renamed the name of the block from `content` to `contenttest`, flushed the cache and then, everything work as expected. i think, there is a problem with the name. I disabled all modules and then, it works with the name `content` too. In my case, the magento tfa module was incompatible with an third party module (an ERP module from BoostMyShop).